# Xpath Reading multiple br line as one line

Tags: xpath, line-breaks

how to read line separated by br as one line, heres the html

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <table>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td class="clas101"> 
  <nobr>Crude Degummed</nobr>
  <br>
  <nobr>Soybean Oil-Crude</nobr>
  <br>
  <nobr>Degummed Soybean</nobr>
  <br>
  <nobr>Oil</nobr>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

i want to read it as one line something like this:

```
//td[class='clas101']/nobr[combineText()='Crude Degummed Soybean Oil-Degummed Soybean Oil']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
//td[@class="clas101"][normalize-space()="Crude Degummed Soybean Oil-Crude Degummed Soybean Oil"]/nobr
```

Comment: this works, i still have problem with nbsp but its not part of my question